# Iterating non-zero elements in MappedSparseMatrix eigen

Tags: c++, r, sparse-matrix, eigen, rcpp

I am passing a small sparse matrix(for testing) to a C++ function from R. The matrix belongs to the class dgCMatrix as shown below:

```
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . .
[2,] 1 1 . . .
[3,] . . . . .
[4,] . . 1 . .
[5,] . 1 . . .
```

I am iterating this matrix as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title2).
My function prints out the value of the iterator and the row index, column index.

The c++ function is defined below:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
using Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;
using Eigen::VectorXi;
using Eigen::Map;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void createRec(RObject sparse_mat, IntegerVector sparse_vec) {

const MappedSparseMatrix<int> spmat(as<MappedSparseMatrix<int> >(sparse_mat));
long int nrow = spmat.rows();
long int ncol = spmat.cols();
NumericVector sim(nrow);

for(int k=0;k<spmat.outerSize();k++){
    for(SparseMatrix<int,Eigen::ColMajor>::InnerIterator it(spmat,k);it;++it){
        cout<<"k="<<k<<endl;
        cout<<"value="<<it.value()<<endl;
        cout<<"it.row="<<it.row()<<endl;
        cout<<"it.col="<<it.col()<<endl;
        cout<<"index="<<it.index()<<endl;
    }
}
}
```

For the matrix given above the following results are printed:

```
k=0
value=156148016
it.row=66211520
it.col=0
index=66211520
k=1
value=0
it.row=0
it.col=1
index=0
k=1
value=1
it.row=4
it.col=1
index=4
k=2
value=1
it.row=3
it.col=2
index=3
```

1.) Any explanation for the values corresponding to k=0? Could these be due to passing the matrix in a wrong manner?

2.) k is iterating over outerSize, which is equal to 5, why is it not iterating for k=3,4? Considering it is a sparseMatrix, this behaviour was expected from the iterator.

Comment: IF I change the declaration of spmat to:     const SparseMatrix<int> spmat(as<MappedSparseMatrix<int> >(sparse_mat)); The issue is resolved for k=0. But I still don't know the reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see very large numbers like `156148016` or `66211520`, chances are you either have an undefined behavior (UB) or a value was not appropriately initialized. In this case, it is the later. Specifically, the [`dgCMatrix` class](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dgCMatrix-class.html)' underlying type is that of a `double` not an `int`.

> The `dgCMatrix` class is a class of sparse numeric matrices in the compressed, sparse, column-oriented format. In this implementation the non-zero elements in the columns are sorted into increasing row order. `dgCMatrix` is the "standard" class for sparse numeric matrices in the `Matrix` package.

Thus, when you are trying to create a map to the memory location of the underlying `RObject` there is an additional step required to recreate the object anew in the requested **different** type. After adding the `const` term, I'm willing to bet the entries are then as expected since the compiler likely keeps in memory the intermediary object.

So, the changing following:

```
MappedSparseMatrix<int> spmat(as<MappedSparseMatrix<int> >(sparse_mat));
```

to:

```
MappedSparseMatrix<double> spmat(as<MappedSparseMatrix<double> >(sparse_mat));
```

should be sufficient.

---

The [linked example](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title2) uses a `SparseMatrix` matrix, here you are using a `MappedSparseMatrix` but do not  setup an appropriate `MappedSparseMatrix::InnerIterator` for the second loop.

Thus, we have:

```
for(SparseMatrix<int,Eigen::ColMajor>::InnerIterator it(spmat,k);it;++it){
```

Going to:

```
for(MappedSparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(spmat,k);it;++it){
```

Also, note that the use of `Eigen::ColMajor` within the `SparseMatrix<int, Eigen::ColMajor>::InnerIterator` is not needed as [that is the default initialization](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html). So, I've removed this statement.

---

Regarding your second question, on the iteration of `k`.

`k` does *iterate* over both `k=3,4` but there are no elements within those columns. Therefore, the inner loop where `k` is output does *not* get called.

This is easy to see if we put two `k` declarative output statements in the outer and inner loops.

e.g.

```
for(int k = 0; k < spmat.outerSize(); ++k) {
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Overall k = " << k << std::endl << std::endl;
  for(MappedSparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(spmat,k); it; ++it) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Inner k = " << k << std::endl;
  }
}
```

---

Avoid `using namespace std;`

Adding in namespace sometimes has unintended consequences, especially one as large as `std`.

---

Taking the points from above and slightly simplifying your example, we have the following bare bones working example:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
using Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;
using Eigen::VectorXi;
using Eigen::Map;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void createRec(Rcpp::RObject sparse_mat) {

  MappedSparseMatrix<double> spmat(Rcpp::as<MappedSparseMatrix<double> >(sparse_mat));

  long int nrow = spmat.rows();
  Rcpp::NumericVector sim(nrow);

  for(int k = 0; k < spmat.outerSize(); ++k) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Overall k = " << k << std::endl << std::endl;
    for(MappedSparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(spmat,k); it; ++it) {
      Rcpp::Rcout << "Inner k = " << k << std::endl
                  << "value = " << it.value() << std::endl
                  << "it.row = " << it.row() << std::endl
                  << "it.col = " << it.col() << std::endl
                  << "index = " << it.index() << std::endl;
    }


  }
}

/***R

# Setup values
id_row = c(2, 2, 4, 5)
id_col = c(1, 2, 3, 2)
vals   = rep(1,4)

# Make the matrix
x = sparseMatrix(id_row, id_col, x = vals, dims = c(5, 5))

# Test the function
createRec(x)
*/
```

Output:

```
Overall k = 0

Inner k = 0
value = 1
it.row = 1
it.col = 0
index = 1
Overall k = 1

Inner k = 1
value = 1
it.row = 1
it.col = 1
index = 1
Inner k = 1
value = 1
it.row = 4
it.col = 1
index = 4
Overall k = 2

Inner k = 2
value = 1
it.row = 3
it.col = 2
index = 3
Overall k = 3

Overall k = 4
```

---

For more details on sparse matrices in Eigen and Rcpp, you may wish to read the [Rcpp Gallery: Using iterators for sparse vectors and matrices](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/sparse-iterators/) by Soren Hojsgaard and Doug Bates.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in such detail.